# Own @types-style declaration in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I want to use `assert` module in `browserify`/`tsify` bundles. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert and https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#builtins and https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html. In short, it's node-js compatible `assert` module in browser, that is browserify builtin.

So I added `@types/assert` to my `package.json`. However the declaration module is not recognized (seems buggy). So I want to do an equivalent of `node_modules/@types/assert` but outside of `node_modules` as `node_modules`  should not be in source control.

Is it possible? If not, can/should I use the `/// <reference` old-school syntax or `declare module "assert"` or what?

Comment: Which one you are using systemjs or CLI

Comment: I don't use systemjs. I'm not sure about CLI but it seems that I use the builtin loader of browserify for CommonJS modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration modules looks OK to me at first glance (no thorough test) but anyway, assuming you are talking about [this library](https://github.com/power-assert-js/power-assert)

Create a `typings/assert/assert.d.ts` directory/subdir/file which will be under source control

the `assert.d.ts` must be constructed as an external module definition, which exports a single symbol `assert`. The content is almost a straight copy of what is found in @types/assert (with the required corrections you mentioned)

```
declare module 'assert' {

    function assert(value:any, message?:string):void;

    namespace assert {

         export function fail(actual?:any, expected?:any, message?:string, operator?:string):void;

         ...

    }

    export = assert

}
```

in `tsconfig.json`, simply make sure that the content of the `typings` directory is included (i.e. not excluded) from compilation.

Comment: Clarified my question. It's not `power-assert` however your suggestions are still relevant

Comment: That would explain that the module declarations "seem buggy" because the definitions loaded from @types/assert clearly mention they are designed for `power-assert`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/assert clearly says "This package contains type definitions for assert and power-assert"

Comment: The approach works with tsc but it doesn't work in Visual Studio. `@types/` worked in both

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the answer of @Bruno Grieder.

How `tsc` finds `.d.ts` files is explained in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

The mechanism of `declare module 'assert'`is called Ambient modules:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules